# recv incoming traffic from server

Tags: c++, windows, tcp

I have the following function setup to receive the data from server every 2 minutes. For the first time i call the function it seems to work but then it freezes at the `recv` call which never returns. and would i need to allocate the buffer on each call even if the server has nothing to send?

```
#define RCVBUFSIZE 32

void Receive()
{   
    UINT totalBytesRcvd = 0, bytesRcvd = 0;
    char buffer[RCVBUFSIZE];     /* Buffer for string */

    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for 
    a null terminator) bytes from the sender */

    bytesRcvd = recv(sockClient, buffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0);

    if (bytesRcvd)
    {
        buffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
        MessageBox(0, buffer, 0, 0); //some way to display the received buffer
    }
    else if (bytesRcvd == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: your `if(bytesRcvd)` check satisfies the `SOCKET_ERROR` (which is -1) condition, meaning you'll try and write to 'buffer[-1]` if there is an error and subsequently head on in to bollock-land!

Answer (score 5):

(1) Your buffer is not really allocated, it's residing on the stack. You typically need not worry about using 32 bytes on the stack.

(2) `recv` is supposed to block until it has something to receive. You can get around that by using non-blocking sockets or by using `select`. Please see [here](http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm) for reference.

In particular, you may

(2a) Use [ioctlsocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738573%28VS.85%29.aspx) to set your socket to non-blocking mode. Then, when you call `read` and there is nothing to read, you'd get the error `EWOULDBLOCK`.

```
unsigned long non_blocking = 1;
ioctlsocket (sockClient, FIONBIO, &non_blocking);
```

Then reading becomes

```
bytesRcvd = recv(sockClient, buffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0);
if (bytesRcvd == -1) {
    if (WSAGetLastError() == EWOULDBLOCK) {
        // nothing to read now
    } else {
        // an actual error occurred
    }
} else {
    // reading was successful. Call to MsgBox here
}
```

(2b) Or, you may call [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to determine whether there is data to read, before actually calling `read`.

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;

fd_set r;
FD_ZERO (&r);
FD_SET (sockClient, &r);
switch (select (sockClient + 1, &r, NULL, NULL, &timeout)) {
    case -1:
        // error
        break;
    case 0:
        // nothing to read
        break;
    case 1:
        // you may call read ()
        break;
}
```

Comment: +1, good answer.  It's also worth noting you can pass `MSG_PEEK` to recv() to check if there's any bytes available to read.

Comment: If I'd go with (2b) then you don't have to pre-allocate or declare buffer of any size on stack. but is still worth to mark the socket as non-blocking with FIONBIO?

Comment: If you're not multithreaded (*and* have a serious bug) setting or not setting `FIONBIO` should make no difference when using `select`-based multiplexing.